# I18n and encoded emails in yaml files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to use the rails built in encoding in the `mail_to` view helper and get that info in my yml locales file?

For example this is what I want

```
mail_to "me@domain.com", "My email", :encode => "javascript"
# => <script type="text/javascript">eval(decodeURIComponent('%64%6f%63...%27%29%3b'))</script>
```

But I want to put it in the middle of my yml locales file. My yml looks like this

```
title:
  desc:
     we would love to hear from you so email us at me@domain.com and
     we'll get back to you asap
```

Comment: what is the part you need to localise?

Comment: i have text to localize and the email shows up in the middle of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love rails, it's already built in to support something like this using variables passed to translations. [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#passing-variables-to-translations)